# Bounded linear operator - translation operator.

Tags: functional-analysis

The image below is from my lecture notes for Linear analysis:
[image: Lecture notes on translation operator]

Shouldn't it be $T:X\to X$? If not, I have no idea what it means, because if $z$ is in $X$ then there is no reason as to why $x + z$ should be in $Y$.

Comment: Could you write it in TeX? I don't get what is is written there!

Comment: @Norbert "Because $T$ is linear, you can use translations. For $x\in X$, the map $$\eqalign{X&\rightarrow Y  \cr z&\mapsto x+z }$$ is continuous..."

Comment: Yeah that's what it looks like. I think it is a mistake and the easiest way to correct is it to change Y to X. The only other thing I think it could mean is: get a linear operator T, and y in Y, and map x (in X) to T(x) + y. Not sure this works. Anyhow, I think the first way was intended.

Comment: @DavidMitra, thanks!

Comment: @AdamRubinson I can see that after the definition of that map its inverse is also mentioned. From their forms it is clear that there is no need in $T$ operator.

Comment: I don't understand...

Comment: You see that and the end of this notes mentioned operator that is inverse to the first one. The inverse is $z\mapsto -x+z$, the original onei is $z\mapsto x+z$

Comment: How can you start talking about an inverse operator, when you have not establish the thing in the first place is actually an operator?

I am still trying to establish what the map actually is. What is Y? Is Y different to X? If so, how can x be in X, z be in X, and x+z be in Y if X and Y are not equal spaces?

Comment: @AdamRubinson the map is the shift on vector $x$, the inverse map is the shift on opposite vector $-x$

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3376/discussion-between-adam-rubinson-and-norbert)

Comment: So does Y=X or not?